# PrimeAgeChecker only returning false

Tags: java

My PrimeAgeChecker is returning false for every age even those that are prime and I can not seem to figure out why this is. I am new to programming and help would be appreciated. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public class Employee {
// fields
String name;
int age;
Department department;
PrimeAgeChecker checks;


// constructors
public Employee(Department department, String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = department;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public int getAge() {
    return age;
}


public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public boolean getChecker(){
    return PrimeAgeChecker.isPrime;
}


public String toString(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(getDepartment() + " ");
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append(getName());
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append(getAge());
    sb.append("\t");
    sb.append(getChecker());

    return sb.toString();
}
}


public class PrimeAgeChecker {

static int ages;
public static boolean isPrime = false;



PrimeAgeChecker(Employee age) {
    ages = age.getAge();
}

public boolean check() {

    if ((ages % 2 == 0) || (ages == 2))
    {
        isPrime = true;
    }

return isPrime;

}

}
```

Fixed Solution

```
public boolean getChecker(){
    PrimeAgeChecker primeAgeChecker = new PrimeAgeChecker();
    return primeAgeChecker.isPrime(getAge());
}

public class PrimeAgeChecker {

static int ages;
public boolean isPrime;


public static void getAge(Employee e){
    ages = e.getAge();
}


boolean isPrime(int ages) {
    if (ages%2==0) return false;
    for(int i=3;i*i<=ages;i+=2) {
        if(ages%i==0)
            return isPrime = false;
    }
    return isPrime = true;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a prime number is? `((ages % 2 == 0) || (ages == 2))` is not enough - that just checks whether the age is *even*, not whether it's *prime*.

Comment: Sorry about that was kind of a place filler to give me some results until I could figure out my main problem. Fixed it, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `getChecker()`, you are returning `PrimeAgeChecker.isPrime` which returns the value of the static variable `isPrime`. `isPrime` is declared to be false, which causes your `PrimeAgeChecker` to always return false.

What you need to do is create an instance of `PrimeAgeChecker`, passing in the age then call the `check` method of `PrimeAgeChecker`.

Your `getChecker` method could look something like this:

```
public boolean getChecker(int age){
    PrimeAgeChecker primeAgeChecker = new PrimeAgeChecker(age);
    return primeAgeChecker.check();
}
```

Keep in mind, as others have mentioned, your logic behind checking whether the age is prime is also flawed.

Comment: My apologies on the logic I should have clarified that that was just put there fast to let me know if my methods were actually checking anything.

Comment: Anyways with your help I was able to figure out a working solution and edited into the original post. If anyone has a similar problem in the future that should help some.